# JS - android landscape zoom

Tags: javascript, android, zooming, portrait

Good day.

I'm writing a JS function that returns true if page is zoomed in android by asking if `document.body.clientHeight < window.innerHeight`.

It works, but when changing to landscape orientation, `document.body.clientHeight` is not updated,
then this condition always returns true.

Now, I tried replacing `clientHeight` with other window/body property but they either don't update on orientation change, OR sadly change when page is zoomed.

I need either:

- a property that updates on orientation change but is fixed when page is zoomed
- a simpler `isZoomed` function for android 2+

thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Tried using the resize event instead? (I have no idea if this actually helps on the problem)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i  catch the event correctly, but the problem is only with the calculation